# Save all items of Listbox to access Database Table in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

I am working on a project and have hit a brick wall again.  I have a listbox with some math operations in it (i.e. "1+2=3").  I am trying to save all items in the listbox to an access database, and I think I am getting close.  The database has two entries I put in manually, but when I use the following code I only get -1's (plus the two manual entries) in the listbox (when I clear the listbox and load the database into the listbox).  The other issue is I need to limit the database to 10 rows which I have no idea how to do. What I would like to do is check the database each time I save to it to see how many rows it has.  If the number of listbox items I am saving will exceed 10 rows in the database then clear the database and start from 0 rows.  Here is the code I have (which only attempts to save to database):

```
con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = Mathops.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim var1 As String
    con.Open()

    cmd.Connection = con
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstDisplay.Items.Count - 1
            var1 = lstDisplay.Items.Item(i).ToString
            cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT into Records (Operations) VALUES(" + var1 + ")")
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

John

Oh...and the database has 2 fields; ID and Operations where ID is the Primary Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using listdisplay.items(i) to get the text from your listbox.

Then to sort out the 10 items issue:

If you do an SQL query:
    SELECT Max(id) FROM Records that will give you the biggest id value in the table

Then check if the value you get back >= 10, and if it is use the SQL:
    DELETE FROM Records to clear the table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I originally did try that.  The problem is it doesn't throw any exceptions at all, it just doesn't save anything to the database.  If I click on the save button and then clear the listbox and then load the database I get all -1's.  But when I check the database there is nothing saved there.

Comment: Export your SQL to the clipboard and have a good look at it so you can see what it's trying to do